# Windows 10 Strange Search Issues

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search

I am on a new laptop and am having very strange issues with Windows Search.

The Windows Key + Typing does search for and return many results.

Oddly enough, even though I have reindexed, restarted services and checked they are running after researching others with this issue, enabled background processes (as a whole in Windows 10 in Settings), etc... New applications that have been installed and have clear shortcuts in the Startup folder still do not show in search results.

Even the most basic of results are not showing.

There is one culprit I feel I might be able to attribute this to - "DoNotSpy 10".

Any ideas as to what I screwed up and what I can do to fix this aside from reformatting (which will be done once I grab an SSD)?

It's a mild annoyance because I know where everything is, but it's got to be something other than the various other threads having this issue too.

I have also gone through Indexing Options and ensured not only the basic folders are being indexed but the startup folders as well. I have even added others for applications that install to %appdata% (e.g. Atom), and I do not get those as results either.

Thanks for any input you can give on this!

Comment: *"There is one culprit I feel I might be able to attribute this to - DoNotSpy10"* Of course, we are always glad to help. However, if you already have a suspicion regarding the root cause of the problem, it would really be helpful if you could elaborate a bit more rather than having us do a Google search to determine what *DoNotSpy10* actually does. Can you please edit your question with that information? That being said, there is probably a a very good chance that program is a contributing factor.

Comment: If you suspect *DoNotSpy 10* is to blame, have you tried, reversing what changes it made to your system to verify that is the case.  Every problem you describe has been known to follow these privacy applications to modify Windows 10.  Hopefully it’s one of those programs which allows you to revert the changes without having to reinstall Windows.